# \hspace error missing number treated as zero

Tags: macros

I have two tabular environments. To redefine the space between them, I used `\hspace` in the following ways:

1. `\hspace[*][1cm]`
2. `\hspace[1cm]`

Both the commands complain the same error, `Missing number, treated as zero`. What should I do?

Comment: It is `\hspace*{1cm}` and `\hspace{1cm}` respectively. Use `*` at the start of line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is:

1. `\hspace*{1cm}`
2. `\hspace{1cm}`

The star is specified without brackets of any kind and the length argument is usually put into curly braces. (They could only be omitted, if the argument consists of one token.)